# I often go for a stroll along the beach

Tags: grammar

Can we use these three preposition with the beach?

> I often go for a stroll **along** the beach.
>
> I often go for a stroll **on** the beach.
>
> I often go for a stroll **at** the beach.

Comment: along and  on are basically the same. At means when you are at the beach but could mean on the sidewalk along the beach. So, the answer is yes.

Comment: Sure, why not ?

Answer (score 1):

> I often go for a stroll along the beach.

My stroll follows the course of the beach for some distance.

> I often go for a stroll on the beach.

I am strolling, and I'm on the beach.  Since almost all beaches are much longer than they are wide, if you stroll *on* the beach, you'll naturally be strolling *along* the beach.  I suppose if you happened to stroll in  little circles, you would be strolling on without strolling along, but who strolls like that?

> I often go for a stroll at the beach.

I wouldn't say that.  "At the beach" means you are roughly in the proximity of the beach.  So you can swim "at the beach" (although you are obviously in the water), make sandcastles "at the beach" (literally on the beach), or frequent bars "at the beach" (even though the bars are physically some distance from the sand).

I suppose, if, whenever you were on a vacation in a beach-town, you were in the habit of going on strolls, not necessarily on the beach but through town and the dunes, then you might say, "I often go for a stroll at the beach", but restructuring it as "At the beach, I often go for a stroll." would make it more obvious what you mean.